# Subgroup label as header in treemap graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I use the treemapify package to create a treemap graph with the subgroup labels.

I want that subgroup labels to not overlap with the normal labels but rather have them as a subgroup header. However, with the option 'place' the subgroup label always overlaps.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)


ggplot2::ggplot(G20, ggplot2::aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, fill = hdi, label=country, subgroup = region)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text() +
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border() +
    geom_treemap_subgroup_text(place="top")
```

[image]

I would like to have subgroup labels above the subgroups, similar as in this example:
[image]

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `padding.y = grid::unit(10, "mm")` argument to position under the top item:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

ggplot2::ggplot(G20, ggplot2::aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, 
                                  fill = hdi, 
                                  label=country, 
                                  subgroup = region)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border() +
  geom_treemap_text(place = "topleft",grow = F)+
  geom_treemap_subgroup_text(place = "topleft", padding.y = grid::unit(10, "mm"), grow=F) +
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works okay for this example but with more countries within a subgroup with will not work anymore....